# JSON.parse(...).reelarray is null - ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

in return i am getting `null` value

```
public function spin()
{
    var decoded : Object;
    trace("i am innnnnnn");
    var sendLoaders:URLLoader;
    var sendRequests:URLRequest;
    sendLoaders = new URLLoader();
    sendRequests = new URLRequest("http://localhost/getspinvalue/4");
    var difvar:Array = [];

    sendLoaders.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, botCompleted);
    sendLoaders.load(sendRequests);
    function botCompleted(e:*)
    {
        decoded = JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.data);
    }
    trace(decoded);
    return decoded.reelarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the  `sendLoaders.load()` is an asynchronous event, your function returns null since the `botCompleted()` function hasnt fired when the function returns

You need to continue the execution inside you botComplete function (if you need to do different things after each spin() you can pass a function that gets executed)

```
public  function spin() {       
    var decoded : Object;
    trace("i am innnnnnn");
    var sendLoaders:URLLoader;
    var sendRequests:URLRequest;
    sendLoaders = new URLLoader();     


    sendRequests = new URLRequest("http://localhost/getspinvalue/4");
    var difvar:Array = [];

    sendLoaders.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, botCompleted);             
    sendLoaders.load(sendRequests);             
    trace("request sent")
}

function botCompleted(e:*) {                                           
    decoded = JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.data);
    trace("data recieved:" + decoded)
    //CONTINUE EXECUTION HERE
}
```

Comment: i just want tht method to return the value so how can i change my code

Comment: when ever i call a spin method it should return my decoded val so how can i change my code.can u please help it out..

Comment: well, it is impossible. You could pseudo-synchronize your code using some technique like promises. But it would still be required to rewrite your code.

Comment: well you cant "just return the value" since there is no value at that point in execution, you have to wait for the complete handler, and then do whatever you were supposed to do with the return value. You need to restructure your code to handle this. If you show more (where the spin() is called and return value used) we can help you better

Comment: i am just calling this method in another as file so tht it is something like ths

Comment: slotObject = checkobject.spin();

Comment: and then what happens to slotObject? If its the same every time, you can use the code above, if its different you need to pass the event to the function, and assign it as the event handler

Comment: spin function is not returning any value.i need the return val frm spin fun..hw can i change my code

Comment: you can change it just like the instructions i gave, but i get the feeling that you dont understand the asynchronous concept - you should probably read up on that

Answer (score 0):

`URLLoader.load` is an asynchronous method, it means that it spawns a process to load URL, and the execution of `spin` continues. So it returns a value at once. The `botCompleted` function is executed when the request is fulfilled, later. Something like that:

```
sendLoaders.load()
return value
botCompleted()
```

So you should rely on the botCompleted function, rather than on the return value. All the logic that depends on the decoded result should be triggered inside the `botCompleted` function.

```
function botCompleted(e:Event):void {
  decoded = JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.data);
  handleDecodedResult(decoded);
}
```

Comment: thanq...i want my spin method to return the decoded value .so how can i change my code.

Comment: That's not possible. You need to restructure your code to work asynchronously. Whatever code depends on `spin()` to return a decoded value simply cannot depend on `spin()` returning a decoded value. Or you need to be move the JSON loading to happen before `spin()` ever gets called. Or you can pass in a callback to `spin()` to handle the JSON when completed. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

> i want my `spin` method to return the decoded value .so how can i change
>   my code.

This is not possible. The JSON data is loaded asynchronously, but the function returns synchronously. In other words, the `spin()` function returns immediately (like all functions do), but the `URLLoader` doesn't complete until later in time. It doesn't matter that the `botCompleted` handler is written before your `return` statement, it won't get called until later. This is what event handlers are for: to handle asynchronous events.

What you can do is pass in callback functions. For example:

```
function spin(callback:Function):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    // .. load
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
    function complete(e:Event):void {
        var decoded:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);
        callback(decoded);
    }
}
```

Now you can call your `spin` function and pass an anonymous function in the context that you call `spin`, which *almost* makes it look synchronous:

```
spin(function(data:Object):void {
    trace(data);
    // Do stuff with data here
});
// Note: data is not available yet from here, only from inside the callback above
```

This is a common practice (in both AS3 and JS), [though not without its pitfalls](http://callbackhell.com/).